# Prove that following limit exists

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

> Suppose that $x_n$ is a sequence of real numbers that converges to $1$ as $n\to\infty$. Using the definition, prove that following limit exists.
> $$\frac{x^2_n − e}{x_n}→ 1 − e \quad\text{ as }\quad n \to\infty.$$

Here is my attempt, Is there anything wrong here?

By hypothesis, given $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N
_1$ implies $|x_n-1|<\frac{\epsilon}{5}$.

$$|\frac{x_n^2-e}{x_n}-(1-e)|=|x_n-\frac{e}{x_n}-1+e|=|(x_n-1)+e(\frac{x_n-1}{x_n})|$$

since $e<3$ and $\epsilon=\frac{5}{4}$ choose $N_2$ sutch that $n≥N_2$  implies $|x_n-1|<\frac{1}{4}$, (i.e
$x_n>\frac{3}{4})$ set $N=\max(N_1,N_2)$

$$|\frac{x_n^2-e}{x_n}-(1-e)|=|x_n-1||1+\frac{e}{x_n}|<|x_n-1|(1+\frac{3}{x_n})<5|x_n-1|<\epsilon$$

for all $n≥N$.

Thank you!!!

Comment: You seem mostly on the right track, but have written some things that don't make sense to me, and I think that they are typos. E.g what do you mean by $\epsilon = 5/4$?

Comment: @CalvinLin I mean set $\epsilon=\frac{5}{4}$

Comment: @CalvinLin I am learning proof writing can you please tell me where the things that don't make sense?

Comment: (Apart from what you just explained) Just because you used $\epsilon / 5$ in define $N_1$ doesn't mean that you must have an $/5$. You should have just " Set $ \epsilon = 1/4$ to get $ |x_n - 1| < 1/4$. ", whereas you said "Set $\epsilon = 5/4$ to get $ |x_n - 1 | < 1/4$."

Comment: Also, you'd want to avoid notation doing double duty. The epsilons that you're referring to are different and should be kept different.

Comment: @CalvinLin why $\epsilon=5/4$ wrong $\epsilon$ can it be any vale greater than zero?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116700/discussion-between-noname-and-calvin-lin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not correct. You cannot decide that $\varepsilon=\frac54$; it can be *any* number greater than $0$.

You can do it as follows. Take $\varepsilon>0$. Now, take $N_1\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\geqslant N_1\implies|x_n-1|<\frac\varepsilon2$. Then, take $N_2\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\geqslant N_2\implies|x_n-1|<\frac12$ and note that this implies that $|x_n|>\frac12$. Then, take $N_3\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\geqslant N_3\implies|x_n-1|<\frac1{4e}\varepsilon$. Now, if $N=\max\{N_1,N_2,N_3\}$, then\begin{align}n\geqslant N\implies\left|\frac{x_n^{\,2}-e}{x_n}-(1-e)\right|&=\left|x_n-1+e\left(\frac{x_n-1}{x_n}\right)\right|\\&\leqslant|x_n-1|+2e|x_n-1|\text{ (because $\frac1{|x_n|}<2$)}\\&\leqslant\frac\varepsilon2+\frac\varepsilon2\\&=\varepsilon.\end{align}

Comment: I got it but I didn't take $\epsilon=\frac{5}{4}$ It is typo then is it correct?

Comment: I take it but I didn't decide

Comment: The verb you use does not matter. You wrote “$\varepsilon=\frac54$” and so your proof is not a valid one.

Comment: but in your third step you had choosen $\epsilon=1$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I disagree with you. That's not what OP is doing in the second part OP just needs to ensure $x_i$ is large enough (bounded away from 0) to make $3/x_i$ small enough. That's why OP did $\max(N_1, N_2)$.

Comment: As a side note, in that first line, there's a minor arithmetic error. It should be $ |x_n - 1 + e  (x_n - 1) / x_n \ldots$

Comment: @noname No, I did not choose $\varepsilon=1$. What I used was that, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=1$, then there is a $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\geqslant\implies|x_n-1|<1$. There is no $\varepsilon$ in this sentence.

Comment: @CalvinLin I have edited my answer. Thank you. On the other hand, I don't understand where is it that you disagree with me. Besides, perhaps that the OP should have take $\frac14$ instead of $\frac54$. I suppose that saying that $\varepsilon=\frac54$ (or, better yet, $\frac14$) should have been avoided; instead (similar to what I did), the OP should have just stated that they were taking $N_2\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\geqslant N_2\implies|x_n-1|<\frac14$. Is that what you think too?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos  $\epsilon=5/4$ wrong $\epsilon$ can it be any vale greater than zero?]